# Facebook like button for facebook single post

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to add facebook like buttons on my website - they should add likes to some posts on my facebook page. The trouble is that though I set a post URL in href, buttons applies to the page, not the post and likes counter shows total likes for page, and not that single post.

```
<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/eightblackdots/posts/837235539689618/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It´s not 100% clear in the docs, but you can only use the Like Button for an external URL or a Facebook Page, but not for single posts or anything else on Facebook.